# Number theory Higher algebra by Bernard and Child

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If a and b are prime to each other, then show that

-)  a+b and  a - b have no common factor other than 2

-) a^2- ab + b^2 and a+b  have no common factor other than 3

Comment: Its said that they have no common factors other than 3...

Comment: How to prove that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If prime $d(>1)$ divides both $a+b, a^2-ab+b^2$

$d$ must divide $(a+b)^2-(a^2-ab+b^2)=3ab$

If $d$ divides $a,d$ must divide $a+b-a=b\implies d\mid(a,b)=1$

Similarly, $d$ cannot divide $b$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$\gcd(a+b,a-b) \mid (a+b)+(a-b)$